# I want to Mask SVG and On scroll it will expand and fit with viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Please help, I want to mask a SVG image (XG) to a section background and when the page will scroll the XG will expand and fit to View Port of the page section.

Below is the code but not working properly. Can any one please help with the code and help with some changes?

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var svg = document.querySelector('.masked-svg');
  var container = document.querySelector('.container');
  var scrollTop = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
  var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;

  svg.style.height = (viewportHeight + scrollTop) + 'px';
  svg.style.width = (viewportHeight + scrollTop) + 'px';
});
```

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.background-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.masked-svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    fill: #fff; /* Adjust the color as needed */
    mask: url(#mask); /* Reference the mask ID */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="background-image" src="https://www.prixgen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/mission.jpg" alt="Background Image">
  <svg class="masked-svg" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
    <defs>
      <mask id="mask">
        <!-- Define the shape or area for masking -->
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <!-- SVG content goes here -->

    <g>
      <path d="M122.3,236.1l-35.9,56.6H40.1l57.2-83.2l-55.6-82.9h47.6l33.5,54l34.3-54h47.1L148.1,208l57.7,84.8h-48.1L122.3,236.1z"/>
      <path d="M365.2,281.3c-19,10.3-40.9,15.4-65.9,15.4c-26.9,0-48.6-7.7-64.9-23c-16.3-15.3-24.5-36.5-24.5-63.4
        c0-27.1,8.1-48.5,24.2-64.2c16.1-15.7,37.9-23.5,65.4-23.5c25.7,0,46.5,4.8,62.5,14.4l-13.3,35.4c-15.9-9.2-31.9-13.8-47.8-13.8
        c-14.9,0-26.8,4.6-35.6,13.8c-8.9,9.2-13.3,21.5-13.3,37c0,16.8,4.2,29.9,12.5,39.1c8.3,9.2,20.3,13.8,35.9,13.8
        c9.7,0,18.6-1.7,26.6-5.1v-24.5H286v-33.5h79.2V281.3z"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I set the height of the page to 400vh so that the page can be scrolled in the first place. I have embedded the image in the SVG and let the SVG take up the entire width.

The two letters are defined in the mask that is used on the image. The letters are placed in the middel of the SVG by the first group (`<g>`) element and move a bit back again in the second group element (the letters take up 325x175 and I move them -80 so that the "scale middle" is in the middel of the "X").

When scrolling I basically calculate how mush the letters should be scaled. It takes some experimentation.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var container = document.querySelector('.container');
  let s = (container.offsetTop + container.clientHeight*.5 - window.scrollY)/container.clientHeight;
  s = (s > 1) ? 0 : 1-s;
  var maskgroup = document.querySelector('#m1 g');
  maskgroup.setAttribute('transform', `translate(1500 750) scale(${1 + s * 90})`);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 400vh;
}

.container {
    margin-top: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 3000 1500" style="border: solid black thin;">
    <defs>
      <mask id="m1" fill="white">
        <g transform="translate(1500 750)">
          <g transform="translate(-80 -87)">
            <path d="M 82.2 109.5 L 46.3 166.1 H 0 L 57.2 82.9 L 1.6 0 H 49.2 L 82.7 54 L 117 0
              H 164.1 L 108 81.4 L 165.7 166.2 H 117.6 L 82.2 109.5 Z"/>
            <path d="M 325.1 158.7 c -19 10.3 -40.9 15.4 -65.9 15.4
              C 232.3 174.1 210.6 166.4 194.3 151.1 C 178 135.8 169.8 114.6 169.8 87.7
              c 0 -27.1 8.1 -48.5 24.2 -64.2 c 16.1 -15.7 37.9 -23.5 65.4 -23.5
              C 285.1 -0 305.9 4.8 321.9 14.4 l -13.3 35.4 c -15.9 -9.2 -31.9 -13.8 -47.8 -13.8
              c -14.9 0 -26.8 4.6 -35.6 13.8 c -8.9 9.2 -13.3 21.5 -13.3 37
              c 0 16.8 4.2 29.9 12.5 39.1 c 8.3 9.2 20.3 13.8 35.9 13.8
              c 9.7 0 18.6 -1.7 26.6 -5.1 v -24.5 H 245.9 v -33.5 h 79.2 V 158.7 z"/>
          </g>
        </g>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <image width="100%"  mask="url(#m1)" href="https://www.prixgen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/mission.jpg"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your reply but the SVG is not Masked with the Background Image. Please see the Page for example what I want https://www.accenture.com/in-en, please see the > svg vector how its works.